# Zipfile Method doesn't works

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-zipfile

I create a zip file with `rockyou` password and I tried to extractall files. But I got some issues. Doesn't matter how password I put in extractall always I will get:

```
('Bad password for file', <zipfile.ZipInfo object at 0x7f7928d14dc8>)
```

Code:

```
import zipfile

zfile = zipfile.ZipFile("./rockyou.zip")

pss = b"rockyou"

try:
    zfile.extractall(pwd = pss)

except RuntimeError as e:
    print(e)
    zfile.close()
```

If I pass a string I got another issue:

```
TypeError: pwd: expected bytes, got <class 'str'>
```

And I tried too:

```
pss = str.encode("rockyou")
```

And:

```
pss = bytes(str.encode("rockyou"))
```

And:

```
pss = bytes("rockyou".encode("UTF-8"))
```

Comment: why are you converting to bytes? why not just pass as string?

Comment: also, don't use `pass` as it's a reserved word

Comment: @RNar  becouse: TypeError: pwd: expected bytes, got <class 'str'>

Comment: @wil93 not is pass, is pss

Comment: try changing `"./rockyou.zip"` to `"rockyou.zip"`

Comment: @wil93 i wrong in "I tried too..." but in the code is pss

Comment: @wil93 "rockyou.zip" I have the same issue...

Comment: Please confirm that you can open the file, with that password, using a standard zip program.

Comment: have you seen [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483138/python-the-zipfile-module-doesnt-seem-to-work-with-passwords)

Comment: @Kevin yes, I can open with an interface program

Comment: @RNar yes, i tried to create a compatible zip but is the same error

Comment: an ugly (but functional) solution is: `os.system('7z e -y -p"password" filename.zip')` after importing `os`

Comment: @wil93, this worked, thanks, but for some reason zipfile method is broken... ;/ i tried a lot of things... but call in cmd worked thks

Comment: I created a zipfile with Unix `zip` and the code worked on that. Try the code on a simple file like that. Perhaps there's something about the zipfile you're using that's incompatible with the library.

Comment: @TomZych i'm on Ubuntu 15.10, can be that? and you used my code on post to test?, if not post yours

Comment: I used your code verbatim, and I'm on Debian. Very similar to your Ubuntu in most respects.

Comment: @TomZych ... i tried in a simple file that contains a txt file and i got the same erros...

Comment: Hmm. What locale is your computer using? Maybe when you type `rockyou` into the zip creator, it's not using the same coding as the Python program is?

Answer (score 7):

Well, I found a way to fix that, works for me, may not so beautiful...

```
  zFile.extractall(pwd = 'PASSWORD'.encode('cp850','replace'))
```

Comment: Thank you for that, was getting `TypeError: pwd: expected bytes, got <class 'str'>`

Answer (score 6):

I've been following the violent python book and in Chapter one you make a mini script to unlock a encrypted zip file. what worked for me was to add a `b` so the string would be in bytes:

```
import zipfile
zFile = zipfile.ZipFile("evil.zip")
zFile.extractall(pwd=b'secret') #this is what i'm talking about
```

Comment: as commented above, looks like that is a compatibility issue between zipfiles encryption, so if you encrypt your file with AES-256 will get the error. i don't know if was fixed, but the correct way is passing bytes in pwd-param and encrypt your file with zipcrypto encription mode.