# python zipflie extractall : password is right but there is a bad password error

Tags: python, passwords, zip

This is  the code :

```
"""
To decrypt a zipfile which has a password.
"""
import os
import zipfile
file_zip = zipfile.ZipFile('dict.zip')
file_zip.extractall(pwd="456789")
file_zip.close()
```

'456789' is the right password but I got a 'Bad password for file' error. 
I have tried many different passwords and files but every time I'm faced with this error. I can't seem to figure out the reason.

Comment: Just tried this on a Mac, works perfectly fine. Can you provide more info about your dev environment?

Comment: Kali-Linux, python 2.7.13, vscode.

Comment: may help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483138/python-the-zipfile-module-doesnt-seem-to-work-with-passwords